# What is the way to force down the position a certain group or paragraph to bottom of page?

Tags: positioning, paragraphs

I wanted to force down the position of a group and I used the following code -

```
\begingroup[b!]
Text
\endgroup
```

But it didn't work out. Is there a better way to force down the position of a group or simply a paragraph at the bottom of the page(not by using footnotes) ?? .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For example

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

Some text.

\vfill

The text moved down.

\end{document}
```

[image]